# Need help with Combinatorics and change of variables.

Tags: combinatorics

I have this very frustrating question that I,ve been trying to solve for the past few hours now and it's killing me here. Basically，I solved the problem, but it's technically not the form we want because it's too complex. My teacher is telling me to use change of variables to make it more simple, but I have no idea how to apply that in a combination situation. Here is my answer, for which we are trying to find 'n'.

$(n-1, 18) = (n-1, 63)$ <<<<<< This is my answer in the $(n, n-r)$ form and my professor wants me to show how that is equal to n-19=63 where n=82 through a change of variables.

Comment: In general $\binom{m}{a}=\binom{m}{b}$ if and only if $a+b=m$.

Comment: Is that applicable to all cases in this form?

Comment: Yes it is. So in particular your condition forces $n-1=18+63$. You might want to look at numbers in a row of the Pascal Triangle: up and then symmetrically down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $k=n-r$, 
$$\binom{n}{r} = \frac{n!}{(n-r)!r!} = \frac{n!}{(n-r)! (n-(n-r))!} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} = \binom{n}{k} \tag{1}$$
this shows that 
$$\binom{n}{r} = \binom{n}{n-r} \tag{2}$$
Since in your problem, $n = n-1 = 81$ and $r=18$, it follows that 
$$\binom{n-1}{18} = \binom{n-1}{n-1-18} = \binom{n-1}{63} $$

Comment: I'm sorry, I am confused now..

Comment: @Ray what confuses you?

Comment: The part where r! turned into n-（n-r）!

Comment: @Ray $n - (n-r) = n - n + r = r$ just look in opposite way.

Comment: Isnt r! Supposed to be r(r-1)(r-2)...ect

Comment: @ray ... yes it is, I didn't use the factorial sign. I just changed the $r$ inside of $(r)!$.

Comment: I don't want to be annoying, but what led you to change r to that because I would have never thought of rewriting r in that situation. Is this something that you just remember?

Comment: @Ray note that I didn't write $r! = n - (n-r)!$ I changed $(r)! = (n-n+r)! = (n - (n-r))!$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14706/discussion-between-santosh-linkha-and-ray).